# NGINX Can't rewrite a url

Tags: nginx

I have a java web application with name RB-war full path is localhost:8080/RB-war but I change the url as localhost/Admin But I can not change this, First redirect is right but when I click a link on this project it either not found or full redirect.

```
 location /RB-war {
    access_by_lua '
     ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE,"Reverse Proxy12 :",ngx.var.args)
    ';
    proxy_pass http://192.168.10.72:8080$uri;
    #rewrite http://192.168.10.72:8080/RB-war/* http://192.168.10.72:8080/Admin/$1; 
    proxy_redirect https://192.168.10.72:8080/RB-war https://192.168.10.72:8080/Admin;
}

location /Admin {
    access_by_lua '
     ngx.log(ngx.NOTICE,"Proxy :",ngx.var.args);
    ';
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header target  $host;
    port_in_redirect on;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.10.72:8080/RB-war/; 
    proxy_redirect default;     
    #proxy_redirect https://192.168.10.72:8080/RB-war/ https://192.168.10.72:8080/Admin/;
}
```